# Combining two piece of SQL code that work in a single query. Learning SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a query to combine data from two tables but from one table I want data output by different groupins

Tried Join, Grouping Sets, Subquery, Union All

Query: To extract the average cost per location per grade (sum for recruitment cost per location)/number of hires per location * number of hires per location per grade

I am struggling with combining two queries - I was wondering if you could help me.

Tables are

Hiring:

```
Location        Hiring Start Date   Hiring Complete Date    Grade
United Kingdom  08/08/2018          29/12/2018              C
United Kingdom  24/10/2018          29/12/2018              B
United Kingdom  24/10/2018          05/01/2019              B
United Kingdom  04/05/2018          15/01/2019              B
United States   16/08/2018          09/02/2019              D
India           09/08/2018          02/03/2019              B
India           15/12/2018          02/03/2019              B
United Kingdom  22/12/2018          02/03/2019              C
United Kingdom  26/12/2018          02/03/2019              B
United Kingdom  26/12/2018          02/03/2019              B
United Kingdom  07/01/2019          02/03/2019              A
United States   06/11/2018          03/03/2019              D
United States   23/01/2019          03/03/2019              A
```

HireCosts:

```
Location        Item            Cost
United Kingdom  Advertisement   640
United Kingdom  Recruiter       926
United Kingdom  Interviews      833
United Kingdom  Admin           211
United States   Advertisement   540
United States   Recruiter       1122
United States   Interviews      934
United States   Admin           192
India           Advertisement   211
India           Recruiter       543
India           Interviews      321
India           Admin           102
```

Here are the two pieces of code that work separately but I would like to combine them into one piece of code

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS HiresperLocationGrade,
       Location,
       Grade,
       (SELECT SUM(Cost) AS HireCost
        FROM HireCosts
        WHERE Location = Hiring.Location) AS RecruitingCostsperLocation
FROM Hiring
GROUP BY Location,
         Grade;
```

This correctly gives me Location, Grade, HiresperLocationperGrade, RecruitingCostsperlocation

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS HiresperLocation
FROM Hiring
GROUP BY Location;
```

This correctly gives me `Hiresperlocation`

My problem is that From Hiring Table I want hires per location per grade and also hires per location
I want Location, Grade, Hiresperlocationpergrade, HiresperLocation, RecruitingCostsperLocation to be output

```
+--------------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
| HiresperlocationperGrade |    Location    | Grade | RecruitingCosts | Hiresperlocation |
+--------------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
|                        2 | India          | A     |            1177 |               28 |
|                       20 | India          | B     |            1177 |               28 |
|                        4 | India          | C     |            1177 |               28 |
|                        2 | India          | D     |            1177 |               28 |
|                       17 | United Kingdom | A     |            2610 |              109 |
|                       44 | United Kingdom | B     |            2610 |              109 |
|                       24 | United Kingdom | C     |            2610 |              109 |
|                       15 | United Kingdom | D     |            2610 |              109 |
|                        8 | United Kingdom | E     |            2610 |              109 |
|                        1 | United Kingdom | F     |            2610 |              109 |
|                       10 | United States  | A     |            2788 |               33 |
|                        4 | United States  | B     |            2788 |               33 |
|                        3 | United States  | C     |            2788 |               33 |
|                       11 | United States  | D     |            2788 |               33 |
|                        3 | United States  | E     |            2788 |               33 |
|                        2 | United States  | F     |            2788 |               33 |
+--------------------------+----------------+-------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I *think* I've aligned those columns correctly?

Comment: I guess the Grade column is empty or duplicated?

Comment: That is your desire or your current output?

Comment: The grade column is populated and only appears in Hiring table. The final posted table is my desired output.

Comment: Can you explain how the column `HiresperlocationperGrade` get their values? I made a working example with your data but dont know how calculate those  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63f4a/2

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide the whole hiring table as it was large. I just provided sample to give example of data and what I wanted output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution with using a left join on subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS HiresperLocationGrade,
       H.Location,
       Grade,
       (
          SELECT SUM(Cost) AS HireCost
          FROM HireCosts
          WHERE Location = H.Location
       ) AS RecruitingCostsperLocation,
       HiresperLocation
FROM Hiring H
LEFT JOIN
       (
             SELECT Location,
                    COUNT(*) AS HiresperLocation
             FROM HireCosts
             GROUP BY Location
      ) HL ON HL.Location = H.Location
GROUP BY H.Location,
         Grade,
         HiresperLocation;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I'm a beginner so for grateful for the help :-)